# How to repair GRUB2 in a system with broken recovery mode?

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

How To Repair GRUB2 In A System With Broken Recovery Mode

Comment: Boot using a live cd and reinstall the grub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solve it this is the way how todo(same boot partition):

Boot into the Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD and click "Try Ubuntu without installing":
[image]
After the desktop is loaded, we need to mount the root partition so that we grant the live cd user read/write permissions on your system files and folders. Let's first identify the partition where Ubuntu is installed with this command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Note: The Terminal can be started by pressing   **CTRL+ALT+T.**

The Ubuntu partition we will work on will be labeled with the word "Linux" as shown in the screenshot given below:

[image]
Run now this sequence of commands to mount the root partition:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/ubuntu

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ubuntu
```

Then you need to mount these system folders to use them on your current desktop environment:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /media/ubuntu/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /media/ubuntu/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /media/ubuntu/sys
```

Now chroot into your hard drive with this command:

```
sudo chroot /media/ubuntu
```

You have now read/write permissions on your root partition. To install GRUB2, you need to use one of these two commands:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

or

```
grub-install --root-directory=/media/ubuntu /dev/sda
```

Note: the "sudo" is not required since you are logged in as root now. Also keep /dev/sda as is.

If the installation is successful, you will get these outputs:

**root@ubuntu:/#** `grub-install /dev/sda`

> Installation finished. No error reported.

Update GRUB2 with this command:

```
update-grub
```

Now Remove the Ubuntu installation CD and reboot your system to see if the GRUB2 boot menu is restored or not.

Comment: +1 from me for the neat answer. It will be better if you can elobarate your answer. Suppose if the user has a seperate boot partition, the method which you have shared wont work. Clarify the same in your answer..